Is the category of topological rings cocomplete?
I'm pretty sure I've read this somewhere but I am unable to find a source for it. Does anyone have any insight?

Why shouldn't it? You give a colimit the induced topology generated by all maps from the small inducing category into it and that should do the job.

@Antonius That doesn't work. Notice that this doesn't give a ring topology.

Yes, it is cocomplete. Let $\mathbb{T}$ be the Lawvere theory associated to rings. Then $\mathsf{Mod}(\mathbb{T},\mathsf{Top})$ is precisely the category of topological rings, and is cocomplete by general abstract nonsense. See for example Lemma 2.6 in Large limit sketches and topological space objects by Brandenburg.

I don't think that we can use the Lemma here. It only shows that the category is complete.

We may use Corollary 7.6 (2). But I think that's far too advanced to get the result here.

The proof can be found here. It is basically an application of Freyd's representability criterion.
